# IOS: Add languages as Localizable.strings

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

I want to localize my app, and I add French and Spanish to the target properties other than English

[image]

But, those languages are not showing inside the file inspector to select. Only 'English' and Something called 'Base'.

[image]

Any Help?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you go to the "Info" pane of your project, you'll see a panel that shows your Deployment Target, Configurations and also the current localizations that you support (including a checkmark for "Use Base Internationalization").  [Base Internationalization](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1467446), b.t.w., allows you to have a single storyboard file that has different string files populating the string fields in the storyboard. [It works for iOS 6 and newer](http://samwize.com/2012/11/22/warning-do-not-use-base-internationalization-in-ios-5/).

When you start, it might look like this:

[image: The Info Pane before adding any localizations]

Here I've added Hindi as a language possibility:

[image: The Info Pane after adding Hindi]

And when you're done, you have the checkbox to choose from:

[image: And here's our new option]

Comment: Is this possible to add new language file dynamically on the basis of server response?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but probably not, @Alok.  Because the iOS app is in code-signed bundle, you can't easily add in resources (like new downloaded localized storyboards or xib files) without them being code-signed or app store reviewed.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add in your Info Project the localizations (I can't add image sorry).

And next you need to create a new file in your project named "Localizable.strings" and Localize this file in your identity menu.

++

Answer (score 0):

Just click on your project in "Info" panel , where you can see "Localizations" and add the languages you want.