# How to change whole app language during runtime in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I have **2 buttons** in my view **(LanguageChangeView)**

- **English**
- **Urdu**

I want to change whole app language **(Like CREEM app)** when user hit urdu button.I also saw many post in **stack overflow** but non of these were working on my scenario.
Please refer me an example or link that could solve my problem.**Thanks!**

Comment: If you are getting labels local add a Plist or any other local source , add all labels in urdu and all other languages you want. When user select language get values for that language

Comment: get this tut first -> [Localization](https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014). Before asking ques first search on google

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOS: Add languages as Localizable.strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843899/ios-add-languages-as-localizable-strings)